# Dice with the same sum at least 5 times

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many times should we throw a pair of dice so that it will be sure that a sum will appear at least $5$ times?

What I did was,
\begin{align*}
C(12,2)& = \frac{12!}{2!(12 - 2)!} = \frac{12!}{2!10!} = \frac{11 \cdot 12}{2}=66\\
C(12,1)& = \frac{12!}{1!(12-1)!} = \frac{12!}{11!}=12
\end{align*}
$66+12=78$

Is this right ?

Comment: If you want to guarantee that there exists a sum that appears at least 5 times, try using the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: so i am wrong 100% right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $11$ possible sums we can come up with. Worst Case scenario, each sum comes up atleast 4 times resulting in $44$ tosses, with $45^{th}$ toss guaranteeing atleast one sum appearing 5 times

Comment: so i am wrong with the way i did it

Comment: @m.s while your answer certainly is wrong, I'm not sure how you came up with the answer, maybe explain that in the post

Comment: i though C(n,r) was ..thats why